# Website working on visual studio but not working on IIS

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7

I have an issue which is now headache for me wasted 4 days in the error.

my Project is working fine on visual studio it contains webservices but when i publish the files in release mode and hosted it in iis then it gives error "500 and error is object reference set to instance".

Guys Please help me out from this

Comment: 1. Deploy debug build to IIS. 2. Use a simple HTML page to trigger w3wp.exe for this site. 3. Attach VS to that process. 4. Trigger that exception and see what VS tells you.

Comment: other website working fine on iis and how to trigger w3wp.exe

Comment: About your error, I suggest you set custom error so that can see detailed error information. Otherwise I can not know which line of code is wrong.
<customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
Object reference set to instance may caused by many reasons. You can check some connection string and resources.  Perhaps the application cannot read the connection string from config file, so it cannot connect to the database to return data, causing the instantiation to fail. This is the most common problem.